# Can anyone identify this RED GINSENG CANDY?

Tags: candy, food-identification

Can anyone identify this RED GINSENG CANDY?  Do you know where to buy?

[image: candy wrapper]

In 1992, a realtor in Edison, NJ, gave me one of these wonderful candies.  She didn't know where to buy more because the Asian supermarkets (in Edison, NJ) stopped carrying them.  I searched the internet, shoppes in Chinatown and Flushing, NY, but saw no candy with similar wrappers.  (My wife says that the non-English writing on the wrapper is Chinese for "Red Tea".)

BTW, there are similar candies available from many suppliers, including Amazon.  Instead of a different manufacturer, I'd enjoy knowing the original brand or company name that produced or produces candy with this wrapper.  Perhaps the original company is still in business and makes something similar to these candies in the photo -- the best ginseng candies made!

Comment: I'm impressed that you've still got that wrapper after 22 years -- they MUST be delicious.

Comment: Actually the wrapper writing in the dark circle says "red ginseng" in traditional Chinese. The candy is Korean though, given the "홍삼" written up at the top. There's nothing else I can make out though, unless there's any more visible writing on the bottom part or edges of that wrapper. I'm personally partial to 'Renesse' candy from the Korea Ginseng Company, but "Korean red ginseng candies" is specific enough that maybe you can just try out whatever you can get locally. (eta: There looks like there's an H Mart in Edison that might be promising. I'd seek out Korean markets specifically.)

Comment: Thanks so much, @Erica too, for your considerate manner of reply.  My uncertainty and craving for the original candy are now satisfied.  I took your advice, bought a tin of Korean Red Ginseng Renege from a vendor in Korea on ebay.  It took a month to arrive. That is why I waited so long to reply.  The candy received is a translucent hard gel candy, very different than the candy I enjoyed in 1992, which was chewy and hit me with flavor.  However, I'm actually happier with this candy, since I bought the sugar free Renege which is better for me and warms my heart as do both of you.  Thank you!

Comment: @janeylicious It sounds to me like that was ultimately the answer.  Why not post it as one?